# Riley word, this helps run things better

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

My prefix is not an animal
and it is not a thing.
My infix a process that happens to all,
cheese, wine, even the king.
The suffix is under the house,
but when it's cut in half.
And all together it's a thing,
you need to run your staff.

Comment: Another Riley puzzle?

Comment: I thought of one more but you guys are too good. You find it right away... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is

> Management

My prefix is not an animal
and it is not a thing.

> It is a "man".

My infix a process that happens to all,
cheese, wine, even the king.

> All three "age".

The suffix is under the house,
but when it's cut in half.

> It's the base"ment".

And all together it's a thing,
you need to run your staff.

> You need management!